# Recommended pattern for setting initialization parameters to custom widget

Tags: dojo

I'm creating my own template based widgets and I was trying to pass some objects through the constructor on creation like this

```
var widget = new myWidget(obj1, obj2, obj3);
```

where my constructor of the widget looks like

```
constructor: function(param1, param2, param3)
```

However I was getting some errors and found they were due to _WidgetBase functionality (specifically the create method) that is expecting something special in the first and second parameters.

```
create: function(params, srcNodeRef)
```

So in order to avoid my parameters nuking the params, and srcNodeRef that was expected in position one and two, I had to move my parameters to after the second position like this

```
constructor: function (params, srcNodeRef, myParam1, myparam2, myParam3)
```

But naturally this is not an expected way to solve this compared to the usual way to instantiate objects in normal object oriented languages (ex. c#)

My question is, is there a recommended pattern for passing initialization parameters to a custom widgets constructor, that avoids this issue of having to remember the first and second parameter positions are reserved?

**NOTE:** 
An important note is that whatever parameters I send into the widget, must be acted on or made available *before* postCreate executes, just like it is if I passed them to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a "dojo" way to pass parameters into your widget:

```
var widget = new myWidget({obj1: obj1, obj2: obj2});
```

In instance of your widget these object will refer to 
`this.obj1, this.obj2`. You don't have to override constructor.

Some comments from dojo source of _WidgetBase on this topic:

```
//////////// INITIALIZATION METHODS ///////////////////////////////////////

        /*=====
        constructor: function(params, srcNodeRef){
            // summary:
            //      Create the widget.
            // params: Object|null
            //      Hash of initialization parameters for widget, including scalar values (like title, duration etc.)
            //      and functions, typically callbacks like onClick.
            //      The hash can contain any of the widget's properties, excluding read-only properties.
            // srcNodeRef: DOMNode|String?
            //      If a srcNodeRef (DOM node) is specified:
            //
            //      - use srcNodeRef.innerHTML as my contents
            //      - if this is a behavioral widget then apply behavior to that srcNodeRef
            //      - otherwise, replace srcNodeRef with my generated DOM tree
        },
        =====*/
```

Comment: I think its working, so I just leave my constructor method signature like this? - constructor: function () - Also how to access the properties once you are in the constructor, I could not find them.

Comment: Try args object:
constructor: function (args) { 
   console.log(args.obj1);
}

Comment: By the way, srcNodeRef also may be useful, you can create your widget like new Widget({},"some-dom-node-id") instead of using placeAt function. In this case your widget will replace this node if it's templated, or will be attached to it.

Comment: @erotavlas, see my comments above, I forgot to reply on comment, so not sure you'll get notification.

Answer (score 1):

I +1'd Kirill's answer as that's the easiest. But from the other comments it sounds like you might need to massage the input or initialize other variables based on the input.

If so, take a look at the `postMixinProperties` [lifecycle method](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_WidgetBase.html#id5) and override it in your widget. If your widget is templated and the template expects the massaged data, you'll need this. In here you refer to your properties with `this` as you expect.

```
    postMixInProperties: function(){
        // summary:
        //      Called after the parameters to the widget have been read-in,
        //      but before the widget template is instantiated. Especially
        //      useful to set properties that are referenced in the widget
        //      template.
        // tags:
        //      protected
    },
```

Don't forget to invoke `this.inherited(arguments);` in here as you should in all of the dijit lifecycle methods.

Defining setters for you properties is another way to massage these properties. You'll want this if a template will use these properties. Example of a setter from the [Writing Widgets page](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#quickstart-writingwidgets). So here 'open' would be the name of the parameter as passed to the contructor, or in a widget template.

```
     _setOpenAttr: function(/*Boolean*/ open){
         this._set("open", open);
         domStyle.set(this.domNode, "display", open ? "block" : "none");
     }
```